# In pandas, the efficient way to get the indices of the rows in table A based the condition from table B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am trying to construct the data good to be consumed for time series modeling.
Now I have two tables:

Table `A`:

```
Index UserID   SessionDate  
0      1       '2020-01-01'  
1      1       '2020-01-03'
2      2       '2020-03-01'
3      2       '2020-03-02'
4      3       '2020-01-05'
```

Table `B`:

```
Index UserID   SnapshotDate  
0      1       '2020-01-01'  
1      1       '2020-01-02'
2      2       '2020-03-01'
3      2       '2020-03-02'
4      3       '2020-01-01'
```

So for each user, at each snapshot date in Table `B`, give me the corresponding the index in Table `A`, if the it satisfies that for that user the session date is less or equal than the snapshot date.

I've tried use the apply function like

```
def index_search(x, df):
    user = x['UserID']
    snap_date = x['SnapshotDate']
    dd = df[df.UserID==user]
    ix = dd[dd.SessionDate <= snap_date].index.values
    return ix

idx = B.apply(index_search,df=A, axis=1)
```

But it is very slow(My dataset is quite large), so I am wondering is there any more efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can try **`numpy broadcasting`**:

```
x1, y1 = A.to_numpy().T
x2, y2 = B.to_numpy().T
mask = (x2[:, None] == x1) & (y2[:, None] >= y1)
idx = [A.index[m].tolist() for m in mask]
```

---

```
print(idx)

[[0], [0], [2], [2, 3], []]
```

Comment: This could work but it would take a lot of memory right? The mask is a huge matrix make it keep showing ```Memory Error```

Comment: @TianqiWang yeah i guess...How big is your dataframe?

Comment: 30M row for each table, so the mask matrix would be (30M,30M), also in my experiment is very slow (Even slower than in pandas apply), but I think it could be a right direction to numpy, but there should be some optimization room.

Comment: @TianqiWang Lets discuss [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219265/data-science-discussions-5)

Comment: It says I need 20 reputation to chat there, while I don't have that much now : (